# What is a "set of forms"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading some notes on algebraic geometry and this is part of the projective variety part. What does this "set of forms" mean? I have not seen it before.

[image]

Comment: I suppose that $S,T,S_{\alpha}$ qre only sets of *polynomials*. See Daniel Perrin, [Algebraic Geometry: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vn1yR9qPvlMC&pg=PA10), Springer (2008), page 10: "If $S ⊂ k[X_1,\ldots , X_n]$, then we denote by $\langle S \rangle$ ... : $\langle S \rangle$ is composed of polynomials $f$ of the form ...."

Comment: I think in this context "forms" means "homogeneous polynomials".